# Can other users on the same mac access xcode accounts?

Tags: xcode, macos, keychain

I'm publishing my Flutter apps for iOS on a service called Macincloud, where i rent a mac using a personal account.
I'm new to mac os, and i have a question about xcode/apple developer accounts:
If i log in on xcode with my apple developer account, can other users on the same mac use that account as well? And do administrators have access to my xcode account?
I'm aware that my certificates are located in my keychain, and that other users can't access those. And i delete my code from the mac everytime i log out, so administrators can't get access to it.
But i'm not sure about how this works with xcode/apple developer accounts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have multiple user accounts on my machine that I use not only for my own stuff, but for clients as well. I create a new user account for each client as way to sandbox things between clients. I do work in Xcode for those clients.

The developer accounts you setup in Xcode in the Preferences are only for that specific user. I switched between a few accounts to confirm this.

Admin accounts can of course circumvent things. For example, my personal user account is the admin whereas my other client accounts are not. When using my admin account, Using my personal account I can change the permissions as I want which would let me see certain things.

However given this is a paid service, I would suspect that unless the admin was rogue, they have very little incentive to checkout out your stuff.